# Matlab internal rate of return

Tags: matlab, financial, symbolic-math

You'll have to be easy on me, I am new to matlab and SO. I am having an issue using the matlab solver to calculate internal rate of return(IRR). I saw that the financial toolbox in matlab had a function for this, however I don't believe I have it installed and did not want to get the trial version on their site.

Given the simple nature of my particular IRR calculation, I figured it would be easy enough to simply code in matlab. It is the same yearly cashflow, so what I put into matlab was as follows:

```
syms x k;
IRR = solve(investment == yrSavings* symsum((1+x)^-k,1, nYears));
```

It doesn't fail, and in fact gives a number. The only problem is the the result is incorrect! I type in the IRR manually and it never equals the investment. Using wolframalpha I found the actual solution, went back and manually typed in wolframalpha's answer, and the symsum function returned the correct result. I'm not sure what's up with the solver!

Answer (score 2):

The way you have the formula written, the symbolic assumption is that you are using x as the iterator variable. I believe you want to use k. Try this:

```
syms x k;
IRR = solve(investment == yrSavings* symsum((1+x)^-k,k,1, nYears));
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! Makes me shake my head that I didn't catch that.

 Now to work on sifting out the complex solutions :)

Comment: `syms x k real` will avoid complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the MATLAB function `roots` to compute the discount factor and then convert that to an IRR. I happened to write such a function the other day, so I thought I might as well post it here for reference. It is heavily commented but the actual code is only three lines.

```
% Compute the IRR of a stream of cashflows represented as a vector. For example:
%   > irr([-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100])
%   ans = 0.059616
%
% If the provided stream of cashflows starts with a negative cashflow and all
% other cashflows are positive then `irr` will return a single scalar result.
%
% If multiple IRRs exist, all possible IRRs are returned as a column vector. For
% example:
%   > irr([-1.0, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.0, -3.7])
%   ans =
%      0.050699
%      0.824254
%
% If no IRRs exist, or if infinitely many IRRs exist, an empty array is
% returned. For example:
%   > irr([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
%   ans = [](0x1)
%
%   > irr([0.0])
%   ans = [](0x1)
%
% Unlike Excel's IRR function no initial guess can be provided because all
% possible IRRs are returned anyway
%
% This function is not vectorized and will fail if called with a matrix argument

function irrs = irr(cashflows)
  %% Overview
  % The IRR is defined as the rate, r, such that:
  %
  %   c0 + c1 / (1 + r) + c2 / (1 + r) ^ 2 + ... + cn / (1 + r) ^ n = 0
  %
  % where c0, c1, c2, ..., cn are the cashflows
  %
  % We define discount factors, d = 1 / (1 + r), so that the above becomes a
  % polynomial in terms of the discount factors:
  %
  %   c0 + c1 * d + c2 * d^2 + ... + cn * d^n = 0
  %
  % Such a polynomial will have n complex roots but between 0 and n real roots.
  % In the important special case that c0 < 0 and c1, c2, ..., cn > 0 there
  % will be exactly one real root.

  %% Check that input is a vector, not a matrix
  assert(isvector(cashflows), 'Input to irr must be a vector of cashflows');

  %% Calculation of IRRs
  % We use the built-in functions `roots` to compute all roots of the
  % polynomial, which are the discount factors `d`. The user will provide a
  % vector as [c0, c1, c2, ..., cn] but roots expects something of the form
  % [cn, ..., c2, c2, c0] so we reverse the order of cashflows using (end:-1:1).
  % At this stage `d` has n elements, most of which are likely complex.
  d = roots(cashflows(end:-1:1));

  % The function `roots` provides all roots, including complex ones. We are only
  % interested in the real roots, so we filter out the complex roots here. There
  % many also be spurious real roots less or equal to 0, which we also filter
  % out. Now `rd` could have between 0 and n elements but is likely to have a
  % single element
  rd = d(imag(d) == 0.0 & real(d) > 0);

  % We have solved everything in terms of discount factors, so we convert to
  % rates by inverting the defining formula. Since the discount factors are
  % real and positive, the IRRs are real and greater than -100%.
  irrs = 1.0 ./ rd - 1.0;

end
```